# Css not loading correctly with https, Tried the solution given in similar queries but not working

Tags: css, ssl, https

I have website and I want to add SSL to that. But when I changed the links to https, my css is not loading correctly. I am not getting what should I change. Please help me, what could be the possible mistake I am doing.

Comment: you're saying the css within your source code ? or double check if you have unsecured cdn link.

Send screenshots of the console so we can visualize.

Comment: You shouldn’t be hardcoding the protocol when linking to css served by your own server. Without error messages it will be hard to help you. Make sure you are using relative paths to your assets.

Comment: Is there any changes to be made in .htaccess file ?

Comment: Compare with HTTP and HTTPS [link](http://www.webhostwala.com/) I tried using relative paths but css are not at all loading

Comment: @Webhostwala: your question provides not enough information to  be sure what is wrong. But I guess you are  simply using the wrong protocol to embed css. I've marked it thus as duplicate of another question. If this question does not fit your broadly specified problem then have a look at the [many questions on this site about similar problems](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+css+not+loading+on+https) and check if they solve your problem or at least figure out what you should check and what kind of information you need to provide so that others can better help you.

Comment: I can see all the images loading properly. But as I have given above the link of my URL , you can the difference between HTTP and HTTPS